# Where to put large configuration data for a general purpose Django app

Tags: python, django, django-views

Tl;dr where do Django users normally put fairly bulky configuration data which is completely site-specific? (so there is no possibility of default values being sensible).

Longer version. I'm most of the way through writing a django app for loading or updating models in bulk from data in CSV files. It is general, in that it can load or update any set of fields of any model (provided the configuration permits!), with the user being able to indicate which columns of the csv correspond to what fields. At present it is accessed through what might become a large number of entries in urls.py, of the form

```
url(r'^loadcsv/customers/', 
    SpreadsheetLoadView( config={
        "model":'customer.Customer', "fields":('name','country',...),
        "otherstuff": ...
    }).view()
```

In passing, if you are wondering about `'customer.Customer'` look up `django.apps` and `apps.get_model`

Anyway, this is less than ideal, because it requires one to know what is the right URL for any particular upload configuration, or alternatively also maintaining an html file containing links to the entire set of currently available operations. I can see myself making a mistake late at night, invoking "customerload" when I meant "customerxxxx" which does something different but also to Customer objects. One is also advised to keep logic out of urlconfs, although whether configuration data like this is "logic" is debatable. Anyway, It would be much nicer to have a single url pointing at a view which handled all currently available csv operations via a configuration structure like

```
config = { 
 "customerload": {
   "verbose_name":  'load new Customer definitions',
   "model": 'customer.Customer', 
   "fields": ('name','country',...),
   "otherstuff": ...
   }, 
 "someotherload": { ...
   },
 ...
 }
```

then the first screen would involve selecting a configuration and a csv file, and the next screen will specify the mapping of columns to fields.

Where best to put this? There are no sensible default values for this stuff. It's something that will be very site-specific and will doubtless be subject to fairly frequent reconfiguration. Should it be stored at `spreadsheetload/config.py` and imported into `spreadsheetload/SpreadsheetLoadView.py`? Or is there some other place and/or form conventionally user for   bulky site-specific configuration?

Comment: @e4c5. Not really my case. That's for a single or short configuration with sensible defaults. In  my case there can be no sensible defaults (except possibly an empty dict). My config  is for completely site-specific configuration of a general-purpose app.

Comment: oops, I had multiple tabs open and gave you the link to the wrong one. Let me try to dig up the right one again

Comment: I don't fully understand your scenario, but as I read it I start thinking of MongoDB. I find it a great tool for dynamic configurations as it allows varying document schemas and can be queried. I may be off base, but its worth a look.

Comment: @SteveJ it's not dynamic configuration. A python file is fine, it's just a matter of how to segregate what may become a widely useful app from site-specific and potentially sensitive  configuration thereof. Really, just wondering if there is a generally recognised way of doing this beyond saying "edit config.py" in the documentation.  BTW since the code is general enough to hack or mangle any objects in one's project that the config permits, putting the config in the DB would have security implications.